# Multiple JS effects on one event

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I've got a bunch of Ajax links in a menu that reload a div called #ajaxupdatediv.  I want to display another div while that's loading the new content, so how would I fire off both effects?

```
<div id="#ajaxupdatediv">
    Content will go here
</div>
<div id="ajaxloadingdiv">
    ...Loading...
</div>
```

Here's a bit of the PHP

```
array(
    'update' => '#ajaxupdatediv',
    'before' => $this->Js->get('#ajaxupdatediv')->effect('fadeOut'),
    'complete' => $this->Js->get('#ajaxupdatediv')->effect('fadeIn'),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger it for all events like this:

```
$(function() {
   //Show loading during ajax...
   $('#ajaxloadingdiv').ajaxStart(function() { $(this).fadeIn(); })
                       .ajaxStop(function() { $(this).hide(); });

   //Hide the content div
   $('#ajaxupdatediv').ajaxStart(function() { $(this).hide(); })
                       .ajaxStop(function() { $(this).fadeIn(); });
});
```

This will hide the content while loading, fade in `#ajaxloadingdiv` when any ajax event starts (leave it if multiple ones happen at once) and hide it when the last ajax request finishes, at the same time, `#ajaxupdatediv` will fade back in.  Using this approach, you don't need to do anything per element/call, these are global handlers, see [`.ajaxStart()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [`.ajaxStop()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) for complete info.